# Gnome control center (system settings) after upgrade missing

Tags: gnome, system-settings, gnome-control-center

After yesterdays upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 I am missing my system settings in main menu (gnome-control-center?). When upgrading I had few errors and had to remove 2 packages: xserver-xorg-video and colord. When I try to install gnome-control-center I get error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libsane : Depends: libsnmp35 (>= 5.8+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: sane-utils (>= 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I have tried installing sane-utils, but I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
sane-utils : Depends: libsane (>= 1.0.27)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try this:
`sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install gnome-control-center`

I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2
Investigating (0) libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 < 20.3~git2010050730.961a8d~oibaf~b @ii mK Ib >
Broken libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 Depends on libsensors4:amd64 < 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mR > (>= 1:3.0.0)
  Considering libsensors4:amd64 -1 as a solution to libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 24
  Added libsensors4:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 via keep of libsensors4:amd64
Investigating (0) libsensors-config:amd64 < none -> 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsensors-config:amd64 Conflicts on libsensors4:amd64 < 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mK >
  Considering libsensors4:amd64 -1 as a solution to libsensors-config:amd64 0
  Added libsensors4:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libsensors-config:amd64 via remove of libsensors4:amd64
Investigating (1) libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 < 20.3~git2010050730.961a8d~oibaf~b @ii mK Ib >
Broken libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 Depends on libsensors4:amd64 < 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mR > (>= 1:3.0.0)
  Considering libsensors4:amd64 -1 as a solution to libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 24
  Added libsensors4:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 via keep of libsensors4:amd64
Investigating (1) libsensors-config:amd64 < none -> 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsensors-config:amd64 Conflicts on libsensors4:amd64 < 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mK >
  Considering libsensors4:amd64 -1 as a solution to libsensors-config:amd64 0
  Added libsensors4:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libsensors-config:amd64 via remove of libsensors4:amd64
Investigating (2) libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 < 20.3~git2010050730.961a8d~oibaf~b @ii mK Ib >
Broken libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 Depends on libsensors4:amd64 < 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mR > (>= 1:3.0.0)
  Considering libsensors4:amd64 -1 as a solution to libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 24
  Added libsensors4:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 via keep of libsensors4:amd64
Investigating (2) libsensors-config:amd64 < none -> 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsensors-config:amd64 Conflicts on libsensors4:amd64 < 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mK >
  Considering libsensors4:amd64 24 as a solution to libsensors-config:amd64 0
  Holding Back libsensors-config:amd64 rather than change libsensors4:amd64
Investigating (3) libsensors5:amd64 < none -> 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsensors5:amd64 Depends on libsensors-config:amd64 < none | 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uH >
  Considering libsensors-config:amd64 0 as a solution to libsensors5:amd64 0
  Holding Back libsensors5:amd64 rather than change libsensors-config:amd64
Investigating (4) libsnmp35:amd64 < none -> 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsnmp35:amd64 Depends on libsensors5:amd64 < none | 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uH > (>= 1:3.5.0)
  Considering libsensors5:amd64 0 as a solution to libsnmp35:amd64 2
  Holding Back libsnmp35:amd64 rather than change libsensors5:amd64
Investigating (5) libsane:amd64 < none -> 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsane:amd64 Depends on libsnmp35:amd64 < none | 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3 @un uH > (>= 5.8+dfsg)
  Considering libsnmp35:amd64 2 as a solution to libsane:amd64 8
  Holding Back libsane:amd64 rather than change libsnmp35:amd64
Investigating (5) sane-utils:amd64 < none -> 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @rc uN Ib >
Broken sane-utils:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64 < none | 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @un uH > (>= 1.0.27)
  Considering libsane:amd64 8 as a solution to sane-utils:amd64 3
  Holding Back sane-utils:amd64 rather than change libsane:amd64
Investigating (6) colord:amd64 < none -> 1.4.4-2 @rc uN Ib >
Broken colord:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64 < none | 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @un uH > (>= 1.0.24)
  Considering libsane:amd64 8 as a solution to colord:amd64 35
  Holding Back colord:amd64 rather than change libsane:amd64
Investigating (7) gnome-control-center:amd64 < none -> 1:3.36.4-0ubuntu1 @un puN Ib >
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on colord:amd64 < none | 1.4.4-2 @rc uH > (>= 0.1.30)
  Considering colord:amd64 35 as a solution to gnome-control-center:amd64 10034
  Re-Instated libsensors-config:amd64
  Re-Instated libsensors5:amd64
  Re-Instated libsnmp35:amd64
  Re-Instated libsane:amd64
  Re-Instated colord:amd64
Investigating (7) libsensors-config:amd64 < none -> 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsensors-config:amd64 Conflicts on libsensors4:amd64 < 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mK >
  Considering libsensors4:amd64 24 as a solution to libsensors-config:amd64 0
  Holding Back libsensors-config:amd64 rather than change libsensors4:amd64
Investigating (8) libsensors5:amd64 < none -> 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsensors5:amd64 Depends on libsensors-config:amd64 < none | 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uH >
  Considering libsensors-config:amd64 0 as a solution to libsensors5:amd64 0
  Holding Back libsensors5:amd64 rather than change libsensors-config:amd64
Investigating (9) libsnmp35:amd64 < none -> 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsnmp35:amd64 Depends on libsensors5:amd64 < none | 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uH > (>= 1:3.5.0)
  Considering libsensors5:amd64 0 as a solution to libsnmp35:amd64 2
  Holding Back libsnmp35:amd64 rather than change libsensors5:amd64
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsane : Depends: libsnmp35 (>= 5.8+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: sane-utils (>= 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: did you mean 21.04? It's not scheduled for release until April 2021...

Comment: My mistake, its version 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Now I get stuck in boot screen (purple with ubuntu). I have to use older kernel to boot properly...and desktop icons are all locked, cannnot move them